# How do I display the original Date using System DateTime C#

Tags: c#

I used the the code below to fine people if they brought the book after it was due. But when I calculate the date of the duedate is changing to 1/1/0001?

I need help keeping the original duedate displayed.

```
private short BookLoan;

private void btnCal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime DateDueBack = new System.DateTime();

    long DaysOverdue = 0;
    decimal FineRate = default(decimal);
    decimal Fine = default(decimal);

    txtDateDue.Text = DateDueBack.ToString();

    DaysOverdue= Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff("d", DateDueBack, txtDateReturned.Text);

    switch (numericUpDown1.DecimalPlaces) {
        case 0:
            BookLoan = 1;
            FineRate = 2;
            break;
        case 1:
            BookLoan = 3;
            FineRate = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            BookLoan = 10;
            FineRate = 5;
            break;
        case 3:
            BookLoan = 30;
            FineRate = 35;

            break;
    }

    if (DaysOverdue <= 0) {
        DaysOverdue = 0;
    }

    if (DaysOverdue > 0) {
        Fine = FineRate * DaysOverdue;
    } else {
        Fine = 0;
    }

    txtDateOverDue.Text = DaysOverdue + " days overdue";
    txtReturnFine.Text = "Fine of " + Strings.Format(Fine, "Currency") + " to pay";
}
```

Comment: Don't rely on VB's implicit DateTime/String conversion. Use an explicit `DateTime.Parse` or `TryParse` call.

Comment: Shade more light please

Answer (score 0):

```
System.DateTime DateDueBack = new System.DateTime();
```

This line is creating a new DateTime object but not assigning a date to it so it will take the default value which is 01/01/0001.

You need to be reading the date due from some source, presumably the database where the book loan is stored.

Also you can calculate the days overdue by simply subtracting `DateTime.Today` from the date due back and getting the total number of days:

```
TimeSpam overdue = DateDueBack - DateTime.Today;
double daysOverDue = overdue.TotalDays;
```

This includes fractional days so you can then round to the nearest whole day or truncate to get the number of whole days as appropriate.

Comment: the display is displaying the original date but calculating with the date value 01/01/0001

Comment: @ChabotaMbola I'm pretty sure that the ToString() Method on the DateTime object is being rendered by the current culture variance on the DateTime Object which is causing it to take the 01/01/0001 and convert it to the System current date.